# How to create own backend functionality for WordPress admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to call a function in the admin panel to fetch and call database records from the backend.

Here is my code:

```
 // Add the admin options page
function cusplugin_menu_page() {
    add_options_page(__('cusplugin Custom Plugin Settings', 'cusplugin'), __('cusplugin Custom Plugin Settings', 'cusplugin'), 'manage_options', 'cusplugin', 'cusplugin_options_page');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'cusplugin_menu_page');

// Add the admin settings and such 

function cusplugin_section_callback() {
    echo __('On this page you can add Custom Style (CSS) to change the layout of Contact Form.', 'cusplugin');
}

function cusplugin_field_callback() {
    $cusplugin_setting = esc_textarea(get_option('cusplugin-setting'));
    echo "<textarea name='cusplugin-setting' rows='10' cols='60' maxlength='1000'>$cusplugin_setting</textarea>";
}

// Display the admin options page
function cusplugin_options_page() {
```

Here I can't understand what I missed in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution ☺ :

```
// Add the admin options page
function cusplugin_menu_page() {
    add_options_page(__('cusplugin Custom Plugin Settings', 'cusplugin'), __('cusplugin Custom Plugin Settings', 'cusplugin'), 'manage_options', 'cusplugin', 'cusplugin_options_page');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'cusplugin_menu_page');

// Add the admin settings and such 
function cusplugin_admin_init() {
    register_setting('cusplugin-options', 'cusplugin-setting', 'cusplugin_sanitize_text_field');
    add_settings_section('cusplugin-section', __('Description', 'cusplugin'), 'cusplugin_section_callback', 'cusplugin');
    add_settings_field('cusplugin-field', __('Custom Style', 'cusplugin'), 'cusplugin_field_callback', 'cusplugin', 'cusplugin-section');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'cusplugin_admin_init');

function cusplugin_section_callback() {
    echo __('On this page you can add Custom Style (CSS) to change the layout of Contact Form.', 'cusplugin');
}

function cusplugin_field_callback() {
    $cusplugin_setting = esc_textarea(get_option('cusplugin-setting'));
    echo "<textarea name='cusplugin-setting' rows='10' cols='60' maxlength='1000'>$cusplugin_setting</textarea>";
} 

// Display the admin options page
function cusplugin_options_page() {
// Enter user code here to duiplay options in admin section
}
```